# How to create CRUD API for a table with compose primary keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, crud

I have a Laravel application to serving CRUD APIs. There is a table with compose primary keys and I introduced the keys in the model as well as in the migration file:

```
protected $primaryKey = ['personel_id', 'valid_for_quarter'];
```

Also I defined its route like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
 Route::apiResources([
    'peopleDatas' => 'API\PeopleDataController'
 ]);
});
```

and the controller class that contains `show` method like this:

```
public function show(PeopleData $peopleData)
{
    dd($peopleData);
}
```

now the questions are:

**1.** What is the url for accessing the show method in this case when the object has multiple primary keys?
Please notice that I didn't defined the route url by myself explicitly and I want to use `Route::apiResources` method. Is it possible?

Here is the routes list:

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/peopleDatas                         | peopleDatas.index                 | App\Http\Controllers\API\PeopleDataController@index                       | api,auth:api |
|        | POST      | api/peopleDatas                         | peopleDatas.store                 | App\Http\Controllers\API\PeopleDataController@store                       | api,auth:api |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/peopleDatas/{peopleData}            | peopleDatas.show                  | App\Http\Controllers\API\PeopleDataController@show                        | api,auth:api |
|        | DELETE    | api/peopleDatas/{peopleData}            | peopleDatas.destroy               | App\Http\Controllers\API\PeopleDataController@destroy                     | api,auth:api |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/peopleDatas/{peopleData}            | peopleDatas.update                | App\Http\Controllers\API\PeopleDataController@update                      | api,auth:api |
```

In other hand should I define the urls in this case explicitly? for example `/api/peopleDatas/{key1}/{key2}` or is there any standard way for it that applies by Laravel?

**2.** If the object has multiple primary keys does the `Eloquent` and [Laravel Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) can handle it and fetch the item from the DB or I need to take the ids from user and apply the `find` function on my model?

**3.** If it does not handle by Laravel itself by default is it possible to override some functions to tell Laravel how to fetch the item from DB in case of `Route Model Binding`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot have a single unique value such as an auto-increment ID as the primary key then have the two additional indexes as a unique composite index?

This would solve your route parameter issue as you would only have a single primary key:

`/api/peopleDatas/{id}`

Your migration would include the specification of a unique composite index:

```
$table->unique(['personel_id', 'valid_for_quarter']);
```

That way your combined columns maintain uniqueness while your route is simplified to a single ID and your relationships can use a single ID also. This will improve performance and well as simplify the code.

Alternatively if you absolutely MUST have a composite primary key you could do so. Your migration would require:

```
$table->primary(['personel_id', 'valid_for_quarter']);
```

Your model would need keys set for the save query (see link)
https://blog.maqe.com/solved-eloquent-doesnt-support-composite-primary-keys-62b740120f

```
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
{
    $query
        ->where('personel_id', '=', $this->getAttribute('personel_id'))
        ->where('valid_for_quarter', '=', $this->getAttribute('valid_for_quarter'));

    return $query;
}
```

And the best solution for the route binding would be to employ explicit route model binding (see link to docs) with your parameter being a delimited combination of your two keys:

`/api/peopleDatas/{people_data}` where people data = `1_3` for example

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding

In your route service provider you would need to specify the resolution logic which would be something like:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('people_data', function ($value) {
        return App\PeopleData::where('personal_id', explode('_', $value)[0])
            ->where('valid_for_quarter',  explode('_', $value)[1])
            ->first() ?? abort(404);
    });
}
```